# Accessing Row Data from ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to pass data from one activity to another on a `ListViewItem` click.

But I am having trouble accessing the data inside the row so that I can pass it to the next activity.

My current code is:

```
final ListView businessListObj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bussinessListView);
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomeActivity.this, bussinessList,
                R.layout.business_list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_ID }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.address, R.id.businessId});
businessListObj.setAdapter(adapter);
businessListObj.setClickable(true);
businessListObj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
{
     Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
     startActivity(detailsIntent);
}
});
```

I have tried

```
Object o = businessListObj.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

But I can't quite seem to figure out the syntax to get the name, address, and id from the object to pass to the next activity.

**EDIT**: XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/businessId"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Small Text"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

**EDIT 2**: BusinessList:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> businessList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Comment: post your `layout.business_list_item.xml`

Comment: @Raghunandan there you go. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Can you post what bussinessList is?  It is clearly a list, but of what kind of object?

Comment: @JonFHancock Edited with BusinessList.

Comment: @FrankJohnson check my post now and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close.

```
Object o = businessListObj.getAdapter().getItem(position);
if(o instanceof MyClass){
    MyClass myObject = (MyClass) o;
    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

    detailsIntent.putExtra("extName", myObject.getName());
    detailsIntent.putExtra("extAddress", myObject.getAddress());
    detailsIntent.putExtra("extId", myObject.getId());

    startActivity(detailsIntent);
}
```

Even better would be to have MyClass implement Parcelable.  Then you could just do:

```
 detailsIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_ITEM", myObject);
```

Then in the activity you could do:

```
MyClass mMyObject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("EXTRA_ITEM");
```

If you need help with parcelable implementation, check out this web app I built that generated your model classes for you from a json feed including making them Parcelable.

http://jsontojava.appspot.com/

I see.  You don't actually have a model.  You definitely need to use the json to java generator and use a real object model.  Every time I have tried to use a HashMap as my model, I have ended up having to rewrite it later.

In that case,

```
HashMap<String,String> myMap = (HashMap<String,String>) o;
```

Then you can pull the values out of the map as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

You have this

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> businessList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

`businessList` is a list of `HashMap<String,String>`

In `onItemClick`

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap<String, String>) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);              
            detailsIntent.putExtra("addresskey",map.get("TAG_ADDRESS").toString());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("namekey",map.get("TAG_NAME").toString());
            detailsIntent.putExtra("idkey",map.get("TAG_ID").toString()); 
            startActivity(detailsIntent);
            // check in logcat  
            Log.i("....................",map.get("TAG_ADDRESS").toString()); 
            Log.i("....................",map.get("TAG_NAME").toString());
            Log.i("....................",map.get("TAG_ID").toString());     
        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. The `map.get()` is returning null in all cases.

Comment: @FrankJohnson how are you populating your `businessList`. the above should work if you do it right